# Primefaces DynaForm surrounding component

Tags: primefaces

I have a question - maybe you can provide me solution for this.

I need to create structure like follow:

```
<div class="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{model.header1}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{model.label1}" />
    <p:inputText value="#{model.value1}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{model.label2}" />
    <p:inputText value="#{model.value2}" />
</div>
<div class="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{model.header2}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{model.label3}" />
    <p:inputText value="#{model.value3}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{model.label3}" />
    <p:inputText value="#{model.value3}" />
</div>
...
```

The problem is that these header DIVs are also dynamically added and contains dynamic components too (so something like DynaForm nested in DynaForm).

I was thinking about creating two DynaFormControls: headerstart with opening `<div>` and headerend with `</div>` but this is not valid (got exception about unclosed tag).

I would be very glad to hear any help.